# Tag for 'smart' watches

Tags: discussion, tags

I've just asked a question about reliability of heart rate measured by fitness watches. I've noticed there are some question about fitness watches. I think it should be one, because it's quite a broad topic, and it's not limited to running.

Should there be a tag, and how should it be named? I hate the name 'smart' watches, because there's nothing smart in them. They just have some sensors, but this what they make with them is not always smart... GPS Watches is somehow broad in German (GPS Uhr) but it's not just GPS. Fitness watches maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @alec says, many questions about things like this are going to be off topic, as we have a fairly narrow use case.

However, one that I've seen before for similar things is "fitness wearables". This would cover a fairly large range of items, from watches to HR monitors and HR straps, etc.

Comment: Wearables then? I think 'fitness' word is of no use, since the whole site is about 'fitness'. Is 'wearable' an established word for a small electronic device with sensors? So that, for example, a headlight, go-pro or my socks are not wearable?

Answer (score 1):

My immediate reaction is that any question about smart watches would be off-topic anyway, because we explicitly don't do purchase recommendations, nor are we a tech support forum.

But if you can think of questions (or rather classes of questions) that would warrant the tag, then we should definitely have it.

Comment: We do allow questions about things like smart watches in the context of a fitness program, much as we do any other sports equipment.